# dlopen a dynamic library from a static library, when the dynamic library uses symbols of the static one

Tags: c++, static-libraries, dynamic-linking, dlopen

This question is closely related to [dlopen a dynamic library from a static library linux C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862272/dlopen-a-dynamic-library-from-a-static-library-linux-c), but contains a further complication (and uses C++ instead of C):

I have an application that links against a static library (.a) and that library uses the dlopen function to load dynamic libraries (.so). In addition, the dynamic libraries call functions defined in the static one.

Is there a way to compile this without linking the dynamic libraries against the static one or vice versa?

Here comes what I tried so far, slightly modifying the example from the related question:

app.cpp:

```
#include "staticlib.hpp"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "and the magic number is: " << doSomethingDynamicish() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

staticlib.hpp:

```
#ifndef __STATICLIB_H__
#define __STATICLIB_H__

int doSomethingDynamicish();
int doSomethingBoring();
#endif
```

staticlib.cpp:

```
#include "staticlib.hpp"
#include "dlfcn.h"
#include <iostream>
int doSomethingDynamicish()
{
    void* handle = dlopen("./libdynlib.so",RTLD_NOW);
    if(!handle)
    {
        std::cout << "could not dlopen: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    typedef int(*dynamicfnc)();
    dynamicfnc func = (dynamicfnc)dlsym(handle,"GetMeANumber");
    const char* err = dlerror();
    if(err)
    {
        std::cout << "could not dlsym: " <<err << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return func();
}
```

staticlib2.cpp:

```
#include "staticlib.hpp"
#include "dlfcn.h"
#include <iostream>

int doSomethingBoring()

{
    std::cout << "This function is so boring." << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

dynlib.cpp:

```
#include "staticlib.hpp"

extern "C" int GetMeANumber()
{
    doSomethingBoring();
    return 1337;
}
```

and build:

```
g++ -c -o staticlib.o staticlib.cpp
g++ -c -o staticlib2.o staticlib2.cpp
ar rv libstaticlib.a staticlib.o staticlib2.o
ranlib libstaticlib.a
g++ -rdynamic -o app app.cpp libstaticlib.a -ldl 
g++ -fPIC -shared -o libdynlib.so dynlib.cpp
```

When I run it with `./app` I get

```
could not dlopen: ./libdynlib.so: undefined symbol: _Z17doSomethingBoringv
and the magic number is: 0
```

Comment: When it comes to static libraries in a POSIX environment, the only linking involved is when your application links with the static library. The static library itself it not linked. In fact, a static library is nothing more than an archive of object files, that are linked into your application like any other object file. Also, the point of using `dlopen` is to load a module during runtime, so you don't need to link with the modules you `dlopen`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I am pretty new to the world of linking. However, my question remains: How do I make the symbols defined in this archive (or in any object file) available to the dynamically loaded library?

Comment: Oh by the way, remember that [C++ uses *name mangling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B). That means the symbol `GetMeANumber` will not be named like that in the object file. To skip name mangling you have to make the function `extern "C"`, as in `extern "C" int GetMeANumber() { ... }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [`dlopen` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html):

> If the executable was linked with the flag "-rdynamic" (or, synonymously, "--export-dynamic"), then the global symbols in the executable will also be used to resolve references in a dynamically loaded library.

That means that for the application to export its symbols for use in the dynamic library, you have to link your application with the `-rdynamic` flag.

---

Besides the problem described above, there is another problem and that has to do with the static library: The problem is namely that since the `doSomethingBoring` function is not called in your main program, the object file `staticlib2.o` from the static library is not linked.

The answer can be found in e.g. [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116420/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-an-unused-static-library), which tells you to add the `--whole-archive` linker flag:

```
g++ -rdynamic -o app app.cpp -L. \
    -Wl,--whole-archive -lstaticlib \
    -Wl,--no-whole-archive -ldl
```

Comment: I had already stumbled upon and tried this flag. Unfortunately, linking the application with `g++ -rdynamic  -o app app.cpp libstaticlib.a -ldl` leads to exactly the same error for my example.

Comment: @Lea I don't have much experience with `dlopen` and friends (just some simple experimenting), but have you tried passing the `RTLD_LAZY` flag to `dlopen`?

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg: Thanks for your continued interest. Yes, I have also tried that, it just makes the error at a different place: `./app: symbol lookup error: ./libdynlib.so: undefined symbol: _Z17doSomethingBoringv`.

Comment: @Lea I figured out the problem, and you're right in a way that it has to do with the static library. Updated answer.

Comment: Just to note that this is a purely Linux answer.  On most Unices, at least in the past, this was the default behavior; there was no need for any special options to the linker.

Comment: FWIW: Posix actually requires the traditional behavior; Linux varies from Posix/Unix in this regard.

Comment: --whole-archive flag causes "multiple definition" errors.

Comment: @MertMertce Then you need to look at your definitions, to make sure you don't have any duplicates. If you can't figure it out, then perhaps post a question about it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg actually, I do have a question about my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649337/linux-dlopen-can-not-find-static-librarys-symbol