# linux dlopen can not find static library's symbol

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-linking

I have an executable project which uses a shared library, that includes a static library. Then from the executable, I try to load another shared library with `dlopen`. That library is found but it cannot find symbols from static library.

Here is the structure:

```
-- SHARED LIB 1
   -- (compiled with) Static Lib 1

-- EXECUTABLE
   -- SHARED LIB 1
   -- dlopen SHARED LIB 2  XX ERROR: SHARED LIB 2 cannot find symbols of Static Lib 1
```

Both `SHARED LIB 1` and `SHARED LIB 2` are linked from `/usr/lib`.

It seems that I miss some flags.

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Your second shared library needs to load your static library as a shared library, or be compiled with it as a static library.  This vitiates the benefits of making it static.

Comment: You have to declare the symbols `extern "C"` (or you have to use their mangled names). Are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

what flags are used to build the "SHARED LIB 1"?
AFAIK -fvisibility won't affect static libs.

However if you use `--exclude-libs` on linking, the "Static Lib 1"s symbol will be removed.

Hope this Question may help: [How to apply gcc -fvisibility option to symbols in static libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222162/how-to-apply-gcc-fvisibility-option-to-symbols-in-static-libraries)

Comment: don't have neither --exclude-libs nor -fvisibility in any project.

Comment: @MertMertce then you should check Galik 's suggestion. besides, any symbol with 'static' prefix won't have external linkage at all.