# -rdynamic doesn't work when using dlopen from static binary

Tags: c++, static-libraries, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

Working on embedded device (ARM, uClibc), I have a static executable which statically linked with different libraries, and have dynamic loading feature using dlopen.

```
set(EXTERNAL_LIBS "-lpthread -lpcap -lcurl -ldl")    
target_link_libraries(myApp -static ${EXTERNAL_LIBS})
```

When loading simple plugin everything **works fine**.

```
void plugin::execute() {
   std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

When adding string variable:

```
void plugin::execute() {
    //THIS IS NOT WORKING
    std::string test = "hello world from thing";
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

I get:

*"can't resolve symbol '_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1EPKcRKS3_'"*

I've tried adding ***-rdynamic*** as suggested here:
[dlopen a dynamic library from a static library, when the dynamic library uses symbols of the static one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095405/dlopen-a-dynamic-library-from-a-static-library-when-the-dynamic-library-uses-sy)
by adding:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -rdynamic  -Wl,-export-dynamic")
```

But it still doesn't work.

**The missing symbol DOES exists in the static binary (verified using nm)**

What am I missing here??

---

Added simplified output of the build process:

**Compiling object files**

```
arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++  -fPIC   -std=gnu++98  -o CMakeFiles/libstaticlib.dir/test1.cpp.o   -c /work/src/test1.cpp
arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc  -fPIC   -std=gnu++98  -o CMakeFiles/libstaticlib.dir/test2.cpp.o   -c /work/src/test2.cpp
```

Linking CXX static library

```
arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi-ar qc libstaticlib.a  CMakeFiles/libstaticlib.dir/test1.cpp.o CMakeFiles/libstaticlib.dir/test2.cpp.o
arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi-ranlib libstaticlib.a
```

Compiling myApp

```
arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++   -fPIE   -std=gnu++98 -o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/main.cpp.o -c /work/src/main.cpp
```

Linking CXX executable

```
arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++   -rdynamic CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/main.cpp.o  -o myapp  -L/work/lib -Wl,-rpath,/work/lib -rdynamic -static libstaticlib.a -lpthread -lpcap -lcurl -ldl
```

Compiling plugin

```
arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++  -fPIC   -std=gnu++98 -o CMakeFiles/plugin.dir/plugin/plugin.cpp.o -c /work/src/plugins/plugin/plugin.cpp
```

Linking CXX shared library ../libplugin.so

```
arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++  -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,libplugin.so -o ../libplugin.so CMakeFiles/plugin.dir/plugin/plugin.cpp.o  -L/work/lib
```

---

output of readelf -s myapp | grep ...:

```
 0021ce74    68 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    2 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1EPKcRKS3_
```

Comment: "The missing symbol DOES exists in the static binary (verified using nm)". Please add as evidence the actual output of `readelf --dyn-syms myapp | grep _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1EPKcRKS3_`

Comment: readelf --dyn-syms myapp have no output (maybe because myapp is static?)
nm gives the following:
0021ce74 W _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1EPKcRKS3_

Comment: `nm` is showing you the global symbol table. `nm -D` will show the dynamic symbol table, and it will not be there. It's not being exported for dynamic linkage, despite `-rdynamic`, but without your code or an [mcve] that's as far as I can get, sorry.

Comment: Figured it, and learned something. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

`-rdynamic` is a GCC *linkage* option. So you can pass it directly to
GCC when it invokes the linker (`ld`). The effect of `-rdynamic` is to
make GCC pass `--export-dynamic` in its invocation of `ld`, as you may see
in the [GCC manual: 3.14 Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

`--export-dynamic` is not a GCC option, but is an [`ld` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html). You
can tell GCC to pass this option when it invokes `ld` by passing `-Wl,--export-dynamic`
to GCC.

So your GCC options:

```
-rdynamic  -Wl,-export-dynamic
```

do the same thing twice: `-rdynamic` would be enough.

But the setting:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -rdynamic")
```

will not cause GCC to pass `-rdynamic` when it invokes the linker.

That is because [`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXXFLAGS.html) sets the options that will be passed to
each C++ *compilation*. Since no linkage happens in compilation, linkage
options are ignored and have no effect. Linkage options should be set in
[`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html),
like:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -rdynamic")
```

**But even then...**

the title of your question will remain true, because `-rdynamic` *doesn't work from a static binary*, period.

From the [linker man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld)

> --export-dynamic
>
> **When creating a dynamically linked executable**, using the -E option or the
>   --export-dynamic option causes the linker to add all symbols to the dynamic symbol table.

My emphasis. And you are *not* creating a dynamically linked executable, because you
are linking `-static`. There will be no dynamic symbol table to which all symbols
could be added.

Here's an elementary demonstration.

**main.c**

```
int foo() {
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return foo();
}
```

Compile and link normally:

```
$ gcc main.c
```

Dynamic symbol table:

```
$ nm -D a.out 
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U __libc_start_main
```

Compile and link `-rdynamic`; see dynamic symbol table:

```
$ gcc -rdynamic main.c
$ nm -D a.out 
0000000000201010 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000201000 D __data_start
0000000000201000 W data_start
0000000000201010 D _edata
0000000000201018 B _end
0000000000000884 T _fini
00000000000007ea T foo
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000000006a0 T _init
0000000000000890 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000000880 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000000810 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main
00000000000007f5 T main
00000000000006e0 T _start
```

More symbols now, including `main` and `foo`.

Compile and link `-static`; see dynamic symbol table:

```
$ gcc -static main.c
$ nm -D a.out 
nm: a.out: no symbols
```

And finally:

```
$ gcc -rdynamic -static main.c
$ nm -D a.out 
nm: a.out: no symbols
```

You just cannot link a program statically if you want a plugin to reference symbols that it defines.

Comment: @MukiD :( You better clean and rebuild your project from scratch with `make VERBOSE=1`, then edit you post to show the complete output of that so we can see what's really going on.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration. you have some idea for a workaround? I'm using static binary to avoid dependencies issues over different platforms

Comment: Is it possible to make a single shared lib of all "myApp" dependencies, including uclibc? And link myApp against it dynamically?

Comment: @MukiD Only if you have static libraries of all of those dependencies, recursively, whose contents that have been compiled `-fPIC`, so as to be linkable into your kitchen-sink shared library. I don't think you'll find those or that it will be practical to make them yourself.